# How to optmize for Cloud Firestore reads using React state?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Single Page App that uses React and Firebase. And the database is Cloud Firestore.

The project is basically an e-commerce, so it has a lot of product fetching from the database.

I'm concerned about how can I optimize for the number of reads that my users will be doing.

Because right now **I have the following code on basically every component that renders products** (a single product or a list of products):

- A `useEffect()` hook that fetches the products from Firestore, that runs on component mount.

**ProductPage.js**

`https://www.mywebsite.com/product/product-slug`

```
useEffect(() => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('products').where('slug', '==', 'product-slug').get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    // STORE RESULT IN STATE
  });
},[]);
```

**CategoryPage.js**

`https://www.mywebsite.com/category/someCategory`

```
useEffect(() => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('products').where('category','==','someCategory').get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      // STORE RESULT IN STATE
   })
},[]);
```

Imagine that a user navigates through the following routes:

- Goes through the `category1` route that renders 20 products per page, and looks up page 1, 2 and 3. **Total 60 reads.**
- Clicks on some product on page 3 and checks out the product page for that specific product. **Total 1 read.**
- Now he clicks back on the `category1` menu and he looks page 1, 2 and 3 again. **Total 60 reads.**

**Result:**

My user made 121 reads, over the same 60 documents.

**NOTE:** the component gets unmounted when the route changes, so the `useEffect` will run again when they go back to the same route, even if they have visited it before.

How could optimize that?

What I thought of doing so far is:

**Note:** it's not a huge amount of products, like 1000 in total, maximum.

**OPTION #1**

Every time a user performs a query on a product category, I'll query that full category and save it to the state in higher level component, like **App.js**. If he is about to query for the same category again, I'll check if I have it on state and return that. It's like a caching layer using React state.

**OPTION #2**

Maybe set up a listener for that query in a higher level component, like **App.js**. Would work very similar to option #1, because I would also have to save the result in state.

Is there a best practice or pattern on how to optimize for reads in this kind of situation?

Comment: You should read about Redux and how it is the single source of truth.
So the Option 1 that you suggest can actually be the redux store where you keep adding the category info when the user visits it. Based on next click, check if the it already is in your store and display it. Local caching :)

Comment: Oh I missed the detail about it being only 1000 products in total. You might get away with using Option 1 as you suggested without redux. But it'll be bad design though IMO

Comment: Hey Shivam. Yes, this would be the exact same concept. But I'll be using `useState` and `useContext` probably. I've read a lot about Redux, and so far I think haven't really needed it yet. What could Redux do for me that I couldn't do without it? Can you show me the selling point? Maybe it's best to work in teams, and as a single developer I haven't see the point so far.

Comment: For me it is that it acts a a global state. So any routing which user does, his session data is fetched only once and stored in the 'global state'. That way if the user traverses back to any of the previously visited pages, I don;t need to make a fetch op again, all I do it look up in the global store and display if it exists

Comment: This might also help : https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles

Comment: I recommend your Option 1 as long as your component tree isn't too deep. Once you start having to pass data and handlers down through 3-4+ levels of components, it can get real messy. At that point, Shivam's recommendation of using Redux is the best way to go. I found the same issue and found that implementing React-Redux was well worth the effort. It really cleaned things up and gives you the caching you want.

Comment: @MurrayR thanks! Are you with a team or do you work alone? Because so far I think I've come up with a pattern of data flow (state and props) that's working well. I still haven't felt the need for redux yet.

Comment: with your code above and with your option1 and 2, they only work when you dont want live update of you data. eg: if document is updated/edited/deleted, you local cache would not reflect the change. in fact, data never get updated until user refersh browser.